# syntax in html to get values from database for Checkbox in DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table with bit column group (1 if checkbox is checked in UI otherwiase 0)

```
<asp:CheckBox Runat="server" ID="chkCodeAppl"  Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Group") %>' />
```

i have written a sp which select this column .But while running it gives error "Specipied cast is invalid".

Please suggest

Comment: can you share the complete aspx code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding (bool) just before binding code :

```
<asp:CheckBox Runat="server" ID="chkCodeAppl"  Checked='<%# (bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Group") %>' />
```